# MySQL validate_password_policy unknown system variable

Tags: mysql, passwords, password-policy

I'm using MySQL 5.7.25 and i want to increase my MySQL password policy by doing this in MySQL command:

```
SET GLOBAL validate_password_policy=2;
```

But i always get an error:

> ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'validate_password_policy'

I tried to list the validate_password variable:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%'
```

but it always return empty set

Comment: it has to be `strong`right not `HIGH`

Comment: _From Manual:_ If the validate_password plugin is enabled, it exposes several system variables that enable configuration of password checking Did you enable the ___validate_password plugin___

Comment: Available values are `LOW, MEDIUM, STRONG` or `0,1,2`  So `HIGH` is not valid

Comment: [How to install](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/validate-password-installation.html)

Comment: @RiggsFolly just updated my question, but still same error

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: http://dasini.net/blog/2018/03/01/mysql-security-password-validation-plugin/

Comment: I dont think you have installed/activated that plugin. Reason is the varibales are only registered IF the plugin is installed. so this `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%'` show nothing because the plugin does not exist

Comment: @RiggsFolly ohh yeah finally after installing the validate_password plugin i can get it done, i'm using ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This problem has happened because `validate_password` plugin is by default **NOT activated**. You can solve by these commands:

> mysql> select plugin_name, plugin_status from information_schema.plugins where plugin_name like 'validate%';

Empty set (0.00 sec)

> mysql> install plugin validate_password soname 'validate_password.so';

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

> mysql> select plugin_name, plugin_status from information_schema.plugins where plugin_name like 'validate%';

Finally, you will show the following:

```
+-------------------+---------------+
| plugin_name       | plugin_status |
+-------------------+---------------+
| validate_password | ACTIVE        |
+-------------------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then  you can  run your command:

> mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';

```
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name                        | Value  |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| validate_password_check_user_name    | OFF    |
| validate_password_dictionary_file    |        |
| validate_password_length             | 8      |
| validate_password_mixed_case_count   | 1      |
| validate_password_number_count       | 1      |
| validate_password_policy             | MEDIUM |
| validate_password_special_char_count | 1      |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec).
```

Answer (score 8):

This command works for me. I'm using MySQL 8.

```
SET GLOBAL validate_password.policy=LOW;
```

Comment: Command work, but then trying change password i get: "Failed! Error: Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements"

Answer (score 3):

> SET GLOBAL validate_password_policy=LOW;

Replace validate_password(dot)policy with validate_password_policy

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i solve this probleam with help this article , i

https://www.percona.com/blog/2020/06/03/improving-mysql-password-security-with-validation-plugin/

#get password root by

#for directadmin system
cat /usr/local/directadmin/conf/mysql.conf

```
mysql -u root -p

INSTALL PLUGIN validate_password SONAME 'validate_password.so';

SET GLOBAL validate_password_policy = LOW;
```